# How can I dynamically change the ImageView?

Tags: java, image, javafx, dynamic, imageview

**Langauge**

Java

**Application:**

I'm trying to create a basic image searcher where I enter a UPC and show a product image on the ImageView.

**Question**

How can dynamically update the ImageView with a new image without creating new instances as I'm doing in my **current implementation below**.

**Current Implementation:**

In my current implementation I have the event handler create a new image and have it set into the ImageView.

```
        searchButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            input = searchBar.getText();
            image = new Image("url link" + input);
            imageView.setImage(image);
            searchBar.clear();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, it is unavoidable. This implementation is perfectly normal. When you create a new `Image`, and set it to the `ImageView`, the old `Image` loses the reference and is eligible for garbage collection.

The long answer is, you can control this behavior to certain extent. You can keep a cache of these images with the help of [`SoftReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html).

```
Map<String, SoftReference<Image>> imageCache = new HashMap<>();

.....

searchButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        input = searchBar.getText();
        final String urlString = "url link" + input; // Or whatever the URL

        final SoftReference<Image> softRef = imageCache.get(urlString);
        Image image = null;

        if (softRef == null || softRef.get() == null) {
            image = new Image(urlString);
            imageCache.put(urlString, new SoftReference<>(image));
        }
        else
            image = softRef.get();

        imageView.setImage(image);
        searchBar.clear();
    }
});
```

This will allows your controller to store a cache of images until the Java Heap runs out of space.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly. The SoftReferences are allowing me to control what gets GC'ed first. My images are SoftRefernces so whenever the heap is full, the GC will look to clear the SoftReferences first. Is that basically what's going on?(I haven't worked with SoftReferences before so I'm trying to understand them.)

Comment: @Kapaz Yes. This is the general behavior. Note that the JVM still have some freedom on how and when it garbage collects. When the heap is getting full, JVM can either garbage collect 1 image, or possibly garbage collect all images, there is no fixed rule on this.

Comment: @Kapaz That's close, but what you wrote is not quite accurate: you don't really get to control what gets gc'd *first*, you get to control what is *eligible* to be gc'd. In "normal" use (no `SoftReference`s, or the related `WeakReference`s), if an object can be reached from a reference in a running thread, it is not eligible for garbage collection. If you wrap it in a `SoftReference`, it *is* eligible for garbage collection, so if memory gets full, it *may* be gc'd.